# Android sqlite exception. Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I run an activity in my Android app with instantiating dbs classes as follows:

```
private final DbOpenHelper dbOpen = new DbOpenHelper(MainMonitor.this);
private final SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpen.getWritableDatabase();
private final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
```

it falls with exception:

```
    07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.analizer/com.android.analyzer.MainMonitor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at com.android.analyzer.MainMonitor.<init>(MainMonitor.java:40)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
07-10 15:33:31.581: E/AndroidRuntime(1142):     ... 11 more
```

DbOpenHelper looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "analyzer";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "network";
    public static final String ACTIVITY = "activity";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NETWORK = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(" +
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement, activity integer default 1)"; 

//  DbOpenHelper openHelper = null;

    public DbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
//      openHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);

    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb) {
        sqliteDb.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NETWORK);
        sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(activity) VALUES(1)");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb, int i, int i2) {

    }

//  @Override
//  public void close() {
//      if (openHelper!=null) openHelper.close();       
//  }

}
```

The problem solved, but the next problem appeared. I've put the insert method in the DbOpenHelper class like this:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb) {
        sqliteDb.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NETWORK);
//      sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(activity) VALUES(1)");
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ACTIVITY_FIELD, 1);
        sqliteDb.insert(DbOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
```

And in Activity I'm trying to update table this way:

```
                    cv.put(DbOpenHelper.ACTIVITY_FIELD, 0);
//                  db.insert(DbOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
                    db.update(DbOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, null, null);

An Exception is:
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:96)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1761)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.analyzer.MainMonitor$2.onCheckedChanged(MainMonitor.java:99)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:125)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:517)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.Switch.animateThumbToCheckedState(Switch.java:508)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.Switch.stopDrag(Switch.java:498)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.Switch.onTouchEvent(Switch.java:458)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-11 15:02:47.341: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I found this line helpfull -

```
at com.android.analyzer.MainMonitor$2.onCheckedChanged(MainMonitor.java:99)
```

and it seems like no table or/and row was created in dbs, that's why it couldn't update itself. What is the problem with this awefully drag-like sqlite? =)

Comment: Perhaps the database file is `null`. Have you tried it on the emulator or just the phone?

Comment: If it may help, the strange thing happens when I try to check wich version of SQlite it uses, the app is fallout and Exception appears in that line where I call - `System.out.println("SQLite version: "+db.getVersion());`, it seems like SQlite is not available at all, or there are a problems, with Writable mode, or something I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activity` is created only after `onCreate` calling. So when you are calling 
`private final DbOpenHelper dbOpen = new DbOpenHelper(MainMonitor.this);` 
activity still not created.
Remove `final` modifier from your db option and init it in separate method after `onCreate` calling.

You should do smth like this:

```
public class MainMonitor extends Activity {
private DbOpenHelper dbOpen;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ContentValues cv;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    initDb();
}

private void initDb() {
    dbOpen = new DbOpenHelper(MainMonitor.this);
    db = dbOpen.getWritableDatabase();
    cv = new ContentValues();
}

//....your code
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a null pointer exception probably in the onCreate  - i dont understand the INSERT INTO network(activity) - surely its just INSERT INTO network  - you do insert into *table name*

But that is not how you are meant to do an insert either - use this example

```
db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put("Description", "Electricity");
insertValues.put("Amount", 500);
insertValues.put("Trans", 1);
insertValues.put("EntryDate", "04/06/2011");
db.insert("CashData", null, insertValues);
```

Comment: I'd commented the insert statement and the exception still the same.

Answer (score 1):

First you can check without inserting. If database is created then you can test to insert.
check data folder, database is created or not.

Comment: How to check the data folder?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the line giving you trouble:

```
sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(activity) VALUES(1)");
```

Try,

```
ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(ACTIVITY, 1);
sqliteDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, v);
```

Make sure you don't insert an empty `ContentValues` object or else an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @zeusakm Try clearing the data and/or uninstalling the app and then running your code again. It could be that you are caching a faulty database and it is never getting removed in your test sessions.

Answer (score 0):

your error lies in this line

```
sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(activity) VALUES(1)");
```

since you are trying to refer to the `activity` column in your table, you should surround it with quotes. It should be like this

```
sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(\"activity\") VALUES(1)");
```

or

```
sqliteDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO network(" + ACTIVITY + ") VALUES(1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

public static final String ACTIVITY = "activity";

I think you can try to change ACTIVITY  field with another name. db object is null or not.
change DB_VERSION value .