# SQLite and Android, moving to next row in database, retrieving and then displaying the results

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to get a phone book working on Android which uses an SQLite database.

The thing I am struggling with, is when I click on my next button I want the next row of data in the database to be brought up. However I keep getting this error when I run the application

03-10 12:05:22.455: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-10 12:05:22.455: E/AndroidRuntime(772): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adressbooktake2/com.example.adressbooktake2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is the code I am using,

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    DBAdaptor db = new DBAdaptor(this);
    int count = 1;
    Cursor cursor = db.getallRecord();



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
        DisplayRecord(cursor);

    }

public void Nextdata (View view){

        if (cursor.moveToNext())
        { 
            DisplayRecord(cursor);
        }           

    }

    public void Previousdata (View view){

        if (cursor.moveToPrevious())
        { 
            DisplayRecord(cursor);
        }
    }

public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c) {

        EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        EditText phoneTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
        EditText emailTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);     
        nameTxt.setText(c.getString(1));
        phoneTxt.setText(c.getString(2));
        emailTxt.setText(c.getString(3));//
    }
```

DBAdaptor.Java

```
    package com.example.adressbooktake2;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdaptor {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdaptor";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AddressBookDataBase1";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AddressBook";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists AddressBook (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "name VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);";


    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdaptor(Context ctx)
    {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try 
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } 
                catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to" + newVersion +
                    ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("Drop TABLE IF EXISTS AddressBook");
            onCreate(db);

        }       
    }

    //--counts rows in database--
    public int rowCounter()
    {
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from AddressBook where id=" + KEY_ROWID, null);
        mCount.moveToFirst();
        int rowCount= mCount.getInt(0);
        return rowCount;
    }




    //--opens the database---
    public DBAdaptor open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //Line 88
        return this;
    }

    //--close the dabatabase
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //--insert a record into database--
    public long insertRecord(String name, String email, String phone)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, phone);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //--deletes a record
    public void deleteRecord(long rowId)
    {
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null);


    }

    //--retrieves a particular record--
    public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor = 
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                        KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONENUMBER}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor !=null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }       

    //--Retrieves all data--


    public Cursor getallRecord() throws SQLException
    {
        {

            Cursor gaCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);                  
            if (gaCursor !=null) 
            {
                gaCursor.moveToFirst();
            }

            return gaCursor;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help that could be given would be much appreciated if you can see where I am going wrong.

The full stack trace of the exception is(2),

> 03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.adressbooktake2/com.example.adressbooktake2.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   com.example.adressbooktake2.DBAdaptor.open(DBAdaptor.java:88) 03-10
>   13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at
>   com.example.adressbooktake2.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:20)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 03-10 13:07:39.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   03-10 13:07:39.579: E/AndroidRuntime(770):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

Comment: For questions like these, you should point out the line where the exception occurs in your code sample with a comment, since we can't go by the line numbers. Also determine what the values of the various variables / subexpressions involved in that statement are. (That is, what is equal to `null`.) this is much easier for you to do with logging or the debugger than by eyeballing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (gaCursor !=null) 
    {
        gaCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    else
    {
        gaCursor.close();
    }
```

Will throw NPE if `gaCursor` is null.

**If it is null, you cant (and dont need to) close it.**

Just remove the `else` part.

You also need to change `DisplayRecord` function. check if `c` is null before calling `c.toString()`.

```
if (c!= null){
    nameTxt.setText(c.getString(1));
    phoneTxt.setText(c.getString(2));
    emailTxt.setText(c.getString(3));//
}
```

Also, you don't instantiate `db` in your DBAdaptor.Java file, Wither use `open()` or add `this.db = db` inside `onCreate` ( using `open` is better)

Comment: I removed it, the same exception still occurs :(

Comment: Is it in the same place again? compare the two stacktraces.

Comment: At what line the NPE is thrown?

Comment: The getallRecord line is the second code window above. It is meant for the cursor to acquire all the database data.

Comment: The NPE is still in the same place even though I have removed the ELSE part.

Comment: This is line 131 Cursor gaCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);

Comment: What is db in DBAdaptor.Java?

Comment: private SQLiteDatabase db;

Comment: I guess you dont instantiate it before using it. Can you add the relevant code?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, instantiate what? SQLitedatabase provides methods to be used within your code.

Comment: Yes but you have to instantiate (using "new") to be able to use an object (db at your code). You can add your code from DBAdaptor.Java so I can explain more.

Comment: The whole of DBAdaptor has been put in there now

Comment: I think you forgot to call your `open()`-method

Comment: Use `DBAdaptor db = new DBAdaptor(this).open()` in your MainActivity

Comment: Still an exception, I will post it up. Thanks for your help, lol. I think this problem might be insurmountable O_o

Answer (score 1):

It's often a source for bugs to do logic before `onCreate()` is invoked. In your case:

```
DBAdaptor db = new DBAdaptor(this);
int count = 1;
Cursor cursor = db.getallRecord();
```

Try to only declare the variables and initialize them in `onCreate`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    DBAdaptor db;
    int count = 1;
    Cursor cursor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

        db = new DBAdaptor(this);
        cursor = db.getallRecord();
        DisplayRecord(cursor);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Also take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412690/android-sqlite-exception-unable-to-instantiate-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        EditText phoneTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
        EditText emailTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
```

like this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
            EditText phoneTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
            EditText emailTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);            
        DisplayRecord(cursor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that the `Cursor` object returned from `getallRecord()` is null...
And the **Null Pointer Exception** refers to the null `Cursor` object accessed in `DisplayRecord()`...

Perform a check before displayin' the records as follows :

```
if(c != null)
    //Display Records
else
    Log.e(TAG, "Cursor is Null");
```

Also it doesn't seem to be the right manner in which contacts are to be retrieved from the database...
There are certain `ContentProvider`'s created to make the data in the database available to an application...[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile) might be of some help...